# Why do requests to my web API only succeed when Content-Type HTTP header is set?

Tags: php, rest, yii2

I'm developing a REST-based web API with Yii2. Through testing, it seems that, in order to be successful, POST requests to the API need to have the Content-Type HTTP header set. (One tester was using Postman without setting the Content-Type header and was receiving 500 error responses in return, while another tester was using cURL and setting the Content-Type header and was receiving 200 success responses. When the Content-Type header is omitted, the POST data seems to be stripped from the request somewhere along the line, and no POST data gets logged by Yii for these requests.)

I was mostly following [Yii's own guide](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-rest-quick-start.html) for development and wasn't aware of any requirements in this area. Could someone explain why the Content-Type header must be set and what is happening otherwise?

Comment: without the code, we cant help

Comment: I don’t think this is a Yii issue ... PHP itself only populates $_POST if the Content-Type indicates that this would make sense (so form/urlencoded, or multipart).

Comment: _“I was mostly following Yii's own guide for development and wasn't aware of any requirements in this area”_ - says right there on that page, in the section about how to enable it accepting JSON input: _“The above configuration is optional. Without the above configuration, the API would only recognize `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data` input formats.”_ And of course the Content-Type header is the one that transports this information (how the data is encoded) in the first place.

Comment: @CBroe, yes, "To let the API accept input data in JSON format, configure the parsers property of the request application component to use the yii\web\JsonParser". Yes, I did that, but on the client side, it seems that a Content-Type HTTP header must be set, and I'm wondering why this is required.

Comment: _“and I'm wondering why this is required”_ - because otherwise how would the receiving end know what to do with the data you send, _how_ it was to be interpreted?

Comment: @CBroe I fully admit ignorance here, but I assumed that the application would just consume any POST data in the request, and just send it to the JsonParser that has been set, in order to do something sensible with it. And that it would just be up to the application to deal with the POSTed data, whatever it is.

Comment: With this in my configuration: `'parsers' => ['application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser']` I guess POSTed data will only be redirected to yii\web\JsonParser if the POSTed data is specified to be in JSON format by the Content-Type HTTP header?

Comment: Yes of course, because it would not make much sense to try and interpret any other Content-Type as JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have discovered by looking in the Yii source code that there is a workaround.

When retrieving parameters that are submitted via POST (or other request methods) by calling the yii\web\Request::getBodyParam() method, the method checks if there is a parser set for the Content-Type of the request, but the method also checks if there is a parser set for Content-Type `'*'` (`elseif (isset($this->parsers['*']))`). So in my Yii application configuration, I just need to set the JsonParser for `'*'`...

```
'parsers' => [
    'application/json' => 'yii\web\JsonParser',
    '*'                => 'yii\web\JsonParser'
]
```

and then I don't need to rely on clients having the Content-Type HTTP header set (as long as I handle the POST data sensibly).